# Mobile browser not loading new css styles

Tags: magento2, css, static-content

I have the Sign Static Files setting on in Magento settings. I have verified that deployed_versio.txt has a new version number after setting up static files with setup:static-content:deploy. However for some reason the mobile Android browser particularly does not load the new versions of the static files like CSS files. It does not load new styles even with page reload. Only incognito mode loads the refreshed styles. Any ideas how to force reload?

EDIT: Case closed. This happened because Porto theme that loaded style file directly and the Sign Static Files functionality did not add the version number to the file path because of that. After renaming CSS file manually and modifying the head.phtml file to load the renamed file it started loading correctly.